# Error when pressing a space, or selecting more cells: "Run-Time error 13, type: mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba

My macro adds multiple values to a selected cell.

When clearing one or more cells (when pressing a space), or selecting more cells, I am getting the error:

> Run-Time error 13, type: mismatch

```
Option Explicit

Public x

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex <> 35 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = Target + x

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    x = Target
End Sub
```

Comment: I had a quick play with it and I couldn't get it to break. You might want to try debugging it using debug.print x and enable the immediate window to review the values being assigned to x as you change selection

Comment: Do you only get the error when you are clearing more than one cell at a time?

Comment: @spikey_richie , when I press space on a selected cell(when I want to clear the cell) then in shows the error. I tried the debugging with debug.print and the right values are assigned, when I change the selection

Comment: @Olly I am getting the error when clearing one or more cells(when pressing a space), or selecting more cells.

Comment: @Georgi Pressing space is not the same as clearing a cell. You're then trying to ADD a space to a number value. You need to test that your `Target.Value` is a number before you try to add it to `x`.

Comment: @Georgi what exactly are you trying to achieve? I can tell you why your code isn't working, but I can't answer what you should do to fix it unless you provide further context of the expected behaviour of your program

Comment: @Olly I added this statement, so I can test the Target: "If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Target = Target + x". Now I think, it works fine. Thank you

Comment: @Rawrplus The idea is to ADD values to a cell(number), now I clear the cell with a space, because when I type 0, it adds 0 to the cell.

Comment: @Georgi `0` does not equal to `Empty` though. Further proven by the fact, the native `IsEmpty()` method returns as `False` on Cell containing `0`, you can explicitly check for values that are 0 and delete them though. Neither is a space, that is equal to string `' '`. If you do `Range` + `' '` it implicitly coerces to `Range.Value` and + acts as an implicit string concatenation in this case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to maintain an incremental sum of values entered in each cell that is colored light green...

You need to deal with single cell values, and test they contain numbers:

```
Option Explicit

Public x As Double

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 35 Then
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then Target.Value = Target.Value + x
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then x = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```